# Trouble validating date entry

Tags: javascript, validation

Needing to validate that user inputs date that is not before 2014 or after the current date. I tried splitting the date entry by "/" and then using parseInt to catch if the [2] spot was less than 2014 but it doesn't seem to work!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<style>

form {border-style: inset;
 border-color: blue;
 height: 360px;
 width: 775px;
 margin: auto;
}
 
</style>

<script>
//Declares 3 arrays
var fullNames = new Array(100);
var dates = new Array(100);
var opinions = new Array(100);

//Global variable
var numOfRatings = 0;
</script>

<script>
//Validates fields are not empty, date is correct then assigns data to arrays
function validateData()
{
 var fullNameStr = document.getElementById("FullName").value;
 var dateStr = document.getElementById("Date").value;
 var opinionStr = document.getElementById("opinion").value;
 
 if (!fullNameStr||!opinionStr||!dateStr) {
  alert("Please complete all fields.");
   return;
   }
 else {
 
 var dateVal = dateStr;
 var dateParts = dateVal.split("/");
 
 if (parseInt(dateParts[2]) < "2014") {
   alert("Invalid date!");
   }
  else {
   fullNames[numOfRatings] = fullNameStr;
   dates[numOfRatings] = dateStr;
   opinions[numOfRatings] = opinionStr;
   numOfRatings++;
   document.getElementById("FullName").value = "";
   document.getElementById("Date").value = "";
   document.getElementById("opinion").value = "";
  }
 }
}  
</script>


<script>
//Displays data held in arrays
function displayData()
{
 var col;
 var pos;
 
 document.getElementById("list").value = "FULL NAME                 DATE            RATING\n";
 
 for (pos = 0; pos < numOfRatings; pos++)
 {
  document.getElementById("list").value += fullNames[pos];
  for (col = fullNames[pos].length; col <= 25; col++)
   document.getElementById("list").value += " ";
  document.getElementById("list").value += dates[pos];
  for (col = dates[pos].length; col <= 15; col++)
   document.getElementById("list").value += " ";
  document.getElementById("list").value += opinions[pos]+ "\n";
 }
}
</script>

<script>
//Clears form
function clearData()
{
 var pos;
 
 for (pos = 0; pos < numOfRatings; pos++)
 {
  fullNames[pos] = "";
  dates[pos] = "";
  opinions[pos] = "";
 }
 numOfRatings = 0;
} 
</script>
</head>

<h1 style ="text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid #999999">Internet Technologies Membership</h1>
<form name ="ratingForm">
 <table cellpadding="10">
  <td>
   <tr>
    <td>Full Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName"></td>
    <td>Date:</td>
    <td><input type="date" id="Date" name="Date"></td>
    <td>Opinion:</td>
    <td>
     <select name="opinion" id="opinion">
       <option value="&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;">Excellent</option>
       <option value="&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;">Very Good</option>
       <option value="&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;">Good</option>
       <option value="&#9733;&#9733;">Fair</option>
       <option value="&#9733;">Poor</option>
       <option value="0">Very Bad</option>
     </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
<br>
<center>
 <textarea name="list" id="list" rows="10" cols="100">
 </textarea>
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="RATE" onClick="validateData();">
 <input type="button" value="DISPLAY" onClick="displayData();">
 <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" onClick="clearData();">
<br>
</center>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date will be retrieved in YYYY-MM-DD format irrespective of what is displayed in the input box.
Try to split it by hyphen (-).

Also while comparing use 2014 as a number instead of string

```
var dateParts = dateVal.split("-");
if (parseInt(dateParts[0]) < 2014)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (parseInt(dateParts[2]) < "2014") {
```

The above part of code is checking the dateParts[2] (an Int) with a string.

You have to make the "2014" part as an Integer too.

So the above line should be

```
if (parseInt(dateParts[2]) < 2014) {
```

Also I would suggest using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) for any DateTime related functionality.